# Is there any testnet faucet site that sends out to bech32?

Tags: testnet, segregated-witness

I am writing a wallet for the far future and I am planning to completely drop the support for receiving to P2PKH addresses. I don't want to add P2SH over P2WPKH either.

Comment: I'm not aware of any.  But I don't understand why you need it?  You can't really drop P2PKH support until we arrive at the "far future" where segwit has completely taken over, and by then surely such faucets will exist.

Comment: I have two reasons. (1) I want to limit my wallet users, [HiddenWallet](https://github.com/nopara73/HiddenWallet) to experts, semi-experts. It is because, HW is an experimental and I'm the sole developer, I want to concentrate on the code and not on support. (2) [ZeroLink](https://github.com/nopara73/ZeroLink/)'s requirement is to start mixing from SegWit utxos: https://github.com/nopara73/ZeroLink/#speeding-up-mixing

Comment: Did you ever find the faucet for this?

Comment: No, however I contacted all of them I could, but only one answered positively (others either didn't answer or "planning to close the service"), though it's not a priority for him. Please ask him, too if you want to see this feature, too: https://twitter.com/metakiwi
The site: https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet