# Segwit Address Supporting Testnet Faucet

Tags: segregated-witness, faucets, p2wpkh

Looking for a good Segwit supporting testnet faucet and preferably one that supports P2WPKH addresses, however answers that allow only P2WSH are fine too.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60127/is-there-any-testnet-faucet-site-that-sends-out-to-bech32

Comment: That question was conflated with dropping support for older addresses and I felt this question was more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [Manu's faucet](https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet) with a [nested p2wkh](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73967/qualities-of-pay-to-nested-witness-key-hash) address NP2WKH.

It will reject native Segwit addresses P2WKH.