# Qualities of "Pay to Nested Witness Key Hash"

Tags: lightning-network, segregated-witness, address-format

The lightning dev tutorial [mentions the `np2wkh`](https://dev.lightning.community/tutorial/01-lncli/index.html#setting-up-bitcoin-addresses) or `Pay to Nested Witness Key Hash` address type, and I would like to find out more about it, so far without success.

Can anybody explain how they are different from other address types, e.g. `P2PKH` or `P2SH`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested P2WPHK is just the normal P2WPKH embedded within a P2SH, to make it compatible with older wallets which don't recognize native witness addresses (bech32). Check out this for more info: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#creation-of-p2sh-p2wpkh-address

Comment: So `P2WPKH ` is the same as `P2WKH`? I guess that was the core of my confusion.

Comment: Yeah its just a shortened acronym because there are already so many characters :)

Comment: Where can I read more about this Address types